# how to define a stack which can get smallest number within O(1)

Tags: algorithm, data-structures

I see an algorithmic question on the internet, it says:

Define a *stack* including a `min` function, through `min` we can get the smallest number in the *stack*, and the time complexities of `pop`, `push` and `min` are all *O(1)*.

I know `pop` and `push`'s complexity is *O(1)*, but I don't know how to make `min` complexity also `O(1)`, if I define a variable to remember the smallest number when `push` every time, but when `pop`, the smallest number maybe change, so I should find the second smallest number, this means `pop` complexity can not be *O(1)*.

So how should I define the *stack* to meet the requirements?

Comment: smallest number in what..a sorted list or is it something else!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Just have another stack with the min values.  When you push a value on your regular stack, push a value on your min stack.  When you pop a value off your regular stack, pop a value off your min stack.  The value that you push onto your min stack will just be the minimum of the current min stack top and the new value.

Here is an example implementation in Python:

```
class MinStack:
  def __init__(self):
    self.values = []
    self.minimums = []

  def push(self,value):
    self.values.append(value)
    if len(self.minimums)==0:
      self.minimums.append(value)
    else:
      self.minimums.append(min(self.min(),value))

  def pop(self):
    self.minimums.pop()
    return self.values.pop()

  def min(self):
    return self.minimums[-1]
```

Comment: @Vaughn, your approach is great, I will accept it if there are no better answers.

Comment: @Anirudh, why do you say it is O(n) ?

Comment: @Anirudh: The number of inputs to what?

Comment: @VaughnCato as mentioned in the question the time complexity of push should be o(1).

Comment: @Anirudh,`push` function in @Vaughn 's post is O(1), it is a constant time, does not vary with the numbers in `stack`.

Comment: @Anirudh it was required to find the minimum value in the stack with O(1) complexity. VaughnCato is right.

Answer (score 1):

This is how I would do it.
While implementing the stack, modify the definition of node as:

```
struct node
{
 int data;
 node *next;
 int min_so_far;
}
```

`min_so_far` holds the minimum value of all nodes below it including itself.
So when you insert a new node, just compare the current node's value with existing top node's min_so_far value, and set min_so_far of new node=min(min_so_far of top node,current node's value)

When you pop, you don't need to do anything.

It's fairly simple to implement.

Comment: your approach seems simpler. maybe `*next` is not needed here.

Comment: @hiway:The stack is implemented by means of a linked list, so I have the next pointer, though there is another implementation which does not have the pointer declared here.

Answer (score 0):

you can hold the min value in a stack variable while `push`ing a value. If the `push`ed value is greater than the next `push` value, then set the `min` variable to the current `push` value.

for example:

```
class _stack {
   int minValue;
   struct stackBucket{
      int data;
   }
   ....
   void push(int lastData){
       //push to the stack
       if(lastData < minValue) {
          minValue = lastData;
       }
  }
  int min(){ return minValue;}
};
```

Comment: This is not o(1) its o(n)

Comment: my `min()` function is independent of the no. of elements in the stack.

Comment: @Aniket its `O(n)` since you are doing this comparison each time an element is pushed into the stack. For n elements you would be doing this n times. Hence `O(n)`.

Comment: @Aniket, if the `minValue` is the top element of the stack, when pops, the `minValue` is invalid.

Comment: @hiway yes, this is what I mentioned in VaughnCato's post as a comment. That his approach works better with push and pop

Comment: What will `pop` look like? I don't think you can get an O(1) `pop` that will update `minValue` correctly. Consider: `push(2), push(3), push(3), push(3), push(1), pop()` - at this stage you'll have to loop through all the elements to find the minimum (2).